# Non-PHP alternative to PHP include

Tags: php, perl, include, ssi

I am attempting to load static navigational content into many pages on my website. Normally I would use either a PHP include or a SSI. However, my university web page server only allows these methods on the club servers (I do club websites too). On the personal page servers, we really only have access to Perl and Python (No PHP, SSI, or Ruby).

So my question is: Is there any way to allow me to include this static content on multiple pages (such as navigationally bars and footers to allow for maintainability) without PHP or SSI?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried asking them to enable SSI?

Comment: JQuery for simplicity of AJAX. Javascript is an option since it runs on local machines rather than server side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, there are many templating engines to choose from; my preference is [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org).

You may want to start reading about it [here](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html#section_Generating_Static_Web_Content).

Comment: It seems like i would need to run this script with every update, I guess it is doable, and I have written a script that puts content into a skeleton file. Okay. I will ask them to turn on SSI, and when they deny my request I will use this method. Thanks.

Comment: @Ross Larson: for dynamic template rendering, see http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html#section_Dynamic_Content_Generation_Via_CGI_Script

Answer (score 0):

As long as javascript is not disabled you can import the static content or dynamic information using AJAX.

You should be able to use jQuery with either Python or Perl [over the CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery). Then use jQuery's [AJAX methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to get your data and insert it into the page.